# Knitr Kable won't output can someone tell me why?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, rscript

I have two Kables, Both will output correctly as a data frame but i want them to be kables as it just looks smarter. This first one works fine as a kable:

```
    #Build tables and convert to df
    #First time=N 
    firstTimeNWork <- as.data.frame(tbl(SDreams, "PassengersInfo") %>% filter(FirstTime == 0 & WorkHoliday == 1) 
                            %>% select(FirstTime,WorkHoliday,Price)) 

    firstTimeNWorkN <- as.data.frame(tbl(SDreams, "PassengersInfo") %>% filter(FirstTime == 0 & WorkHoliday == 0) 
                             %>% select(FirstTime,WorkHoliday,Price))

    #First time=Y
    firstTimeYWork <- as.data.frame(tbl(SDreams, "PassengersInfo") %>% filter(FirstTime == 1 & WorkHoliday == 1) 
                            %>% select(FirstTime,WorkHoliday,Price))

    firstTimeYWorkN <- as.data.frame(tbl(SDreams, "PassengersInfo") %>% filter(FirstTime == 1 & WorkHoliday == 0) 
                             %>% select(FirstTime,WorkHoliday,Price))

    #Setup headings for the outputted table
    FirstTime <- c('No',' ','Yes',' ')

    WorkHoliday<- c('Yes','No','Yes','No')

    #Find out average amount paid based on the tables i created
    #First time=N
    firstTimeNWorkMean <- mean(firstTimeNWork$Price)
    firstTimeNWorkNMean <- mean(firstTimeNWorkN$Price)
    #First time=Y
    firstTimeYWorkMean <- mean(firstTimeYWork$Price)
    firstTimeYWorkNMean <- mean(firstTimeYWorkN$Price)

    #Add values under heading
    MeanPrice <-c(firstTimeNWorkMean,firstTimeNWorkNMean,firstTimeYWorkMean,firstTimeYWorkNMean)
    #Create the output df
    passengerSummary1 <- data.frame(FirstTime,WorkHoliday,MeanPrice)
    #Label columns & display
    kable(passengerSummary1,
  col.names = c("First time travelling?","As part of work?","Average price paid in (£)"), 
  align = c("c","c","c"),digits = 0)
```

However the second Kable won't create:

```
    #Create tables
    wouldVisitAgainNPrice <- as.data.frame(tbl(SDreams, "PassengersInfo") %>% filter(Propensity == 1)
                                  %>% select(Propensity,Price))
    wouldVisitAgainYPrice <- as.data.frame(tbl(SDreams, "PassengersInfo") %>% filter(Propensity == 2)
                                  %>% select(Propensity,Price))
    #Count amount of passengers based on filter
    wouldVisitAgainNPriceTab <-tabulate(wouldVisitAgainNPrice$Propensity)
    wouldVisitAgainYPriceTab <-tabulate(wouldVisitAgainYPrice$Propensity)[[2]]
    #Setup column
    WouldVisitAgain <-c('No','Yes')
    #Add column with values 
    Passengers <-c(wouldVisitAgainNPriceTab,wouldVisitAgainYPriceTab)
    #Means of prices
    wouldVisitAgainNPriceMean <-mean(wouldVisitAgainNPrice$Price)
    wouldVisitAgainYPriceMean <-mean(wouldVisitAgainYPrice$Price)
    #Add column with price values
    MeanPrice2 <-c(wouldVisitAgainNPriceMean,wouldVisitAgainYPriceMean)
    #Create df 
    passengerSummary2 <-data.frame(WouldVisitAgain,Passengers,MeanPrice2)
    #Label columns & display
    kable(passengerSummary2,
    col.names = c("Would visit again?","No of Passengers","Mean Price in (£)"), 
  align = c("c","c","c"),digits = 0)
```

And as you can tell the kable code is exactly the same so i am very confused as to why it won't work. I have tried updating all my packages and restarting R Studio and removing objects however none of that has made any difference.

Sorry in advance for the amount of code and how bad it is.I am new to this so i am aware i have likely done something pretty stupid and will be questioned about why i did that and my only answer will be I'm new,I'll remember that and maybe try it out if i have time.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help with this :)

Comment: When you say the second table won't create, do you see any output at all? Or just a blank spot where you wanted it to appear in the RMarkdown output?

Comment: Just a blank spot

Comment: What does the object `passengerSummary2` look like? This may not be a `kable` problem.

Comment: It looks like [this](http://prntscr.com/fy27mt) however the value types are the same in table one so I'm not sure where the difference is that is causing the issue.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this at all?